# Java code using Tween Engine not working

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics

i want to add animation effects to a JLabel for that i am using this library : http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/. 
But
this code is not producing the animation. I know i am doing it wrong. Please provide the correct way. I have read the tutorial on this page https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/wiki/GetStarted. But i am still not able to figure it out.....

```
    public class ParticleAccessor extends javax.swing.JFrame implements TweenAccessor<JLabel>{
        public ParticleAccessor() {
            initComponents();
        }

        private void initComponents() {

        }
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ParticleAccessor pa = new ParticleAccessor();
                    pa.setVisible(true);
                    TweenManager m = new TweenManager();
                    Tween.registerAccessor(JLabel.class, pa);
                    Tween.to(particle1, ParticleAccessor.POSITION_XY, 1.0f)
                        .target(100, 200)
                        .start(m);

                    Tween.to(particle2, ParticleAccessor.POSITION_XY, 0.5f)
                        .target(0, 0)
                        .ease(Bounce.OUT)
                        .delay(1.0f)
                        .repeatYoyo(2, 0.5f)
                        .start();
                    m.update(50);
                }
            });
        }
        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private static javax.swing.JLabel particle1;
        private static javax.swing.JLabel particle2;
        // End of variables declaration                   

        public static final int POSITION_X = 1;
        public static final int POSITION_Y = 2;
        public static final int POSITION_XY = 3;

        // TweenAccessor implementation

        @Override
        public int getValues(JLabel target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {
            switch (tweenType) {
                case POSITION_X: returnValues[0] = target.getX(); return 1;
                case POSITION_Y: returnValues[0] = target.getY(); return 1;
                case POSITION_XY:
                    returnValues[0] = target.getX();
                    returnValues[1] = target.getY();
                    return 2;
                default: assert false; return -1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setValues(JLabel target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
            switch (tweenType) {
                case POSITION_X: target.setAlignmentX(newValues[0]); break;
                case POSITION_Y: target.setAlignmentY(newValues[0]); break;
                case POSITION_XY:
                    target.setAlignmentX(newValues[0]);
                    target.setAlignmentY(newValues[1]);
                    break;
                default: assert false; break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your TweenManager outside the anonymous class. Make it public static so you can access it from anywhere. Then you'll need to update your manager with the amount of time passed as often as you can. To do that, you'll have to make another thread that runs in a loop and constantly calls manager.update(timePassed). Try something like this:

```
public class MyThread
    extends Thread
{
  private long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
      while(true){
        MyGUIProgram.tweenManager.update((System.currentTimeMillis() - time)/1000);
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
      }
  }
}
```

Then, start that thread in the constructor of your main object.